# multiple asynchronous calls from flex

Tags: php, apache-flex, apache

I am using dashboard component in flex.In the component 6 service calls are made simultaneously and all the calls are independent of each other. The result of the service calls are xml which then populate 6 graphs in the dashboard in 6 different panels. The problem is the server sometimes become unresponsive when these 6 calls are made. It tries to fetch for sometime and later throws http request error. Then I tried to make all the synchronous. On the result handler of first call, second service called and so on. Now the server responses in fine way. I want to know the reason why the server becomes unresponsive when asynchronous calls are made.

Comment: I think your problem may be more related to your server setup than the Flex application.

Comment: Can you provide more details, we are using apache server and for backend we are using php.

Comment: It is _you_ who has to provide more details: how can we possibly start to figure out what is wrong with your setup if all we know is that you're using Apache/Php. I'll re-tag the question for you so people with more knowledge about the matter can have a say in this, but I suggest you add more information to your question.

Comment: Actually I am doing the flex part only and have no idea about the server setup. I want to make sure that nothing is wrong with the flex part and if there is then I need to figure it out.

Comment: In that case: there is nothing wrong with making 6 calls at the same time from a Flex app.

Comment: Since you have no control over the server side; you may consider timing your calls.  Then you can go back to the server folks and say "When I make these 6 calls it takes Y amount of time; is this expected?"  Using a Timer class is one way to time them.  @RIAStar is there a "getTickCount()" style function in ActionScript?  I thought yes, but couldn't find it by Googling.

Comment: When the problem happens, what errors do you see in the server logs? You can start to determine if this is a client or server issue by seeing what the server says about those 6 requests: did they all complete with a "200" status (ok) or a some other failure status?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com [getTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer()); however, since the OP is getting timeouts from the server, I'm not sure that'll be of much help.

Comment: @RIAstar Yep; getTmer() Was what I was thinking of; but yes you're right if the server times out it won't be much use.

Comment: Have you checked whether other applications are also making calls to the server, thereby the load during the time you had the problem was very high? Unless you got access to server logs, it would be difficult to optimize the server calls.

Comment: I have no access to server logs.I checked into the firebug, server call request are made for some time, and finally gives HTTP server error. But when I made all the calls synchronous, things are working fine. For now things are working fine, but still don't know the exact reason why things were not working fine previously. I know that no other services were accessing the server at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the 6 calls are made at the same time and the service creates 6 instances.

It can be hard for your server !

Comment: yes the 6 calls are made at the same time, but that's the way asynchronous mechanism works. The service calls are queued up before getting processed by the server, then where is the problem. If I make say 2 asynchronous calls at the same time, will the problem still exist?